# Google Colab: Save large file to team drive

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I want to download a large file to my google team drive trough google colab (~80 GB). I mounted Google Drive with:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

After that, I started the download using [gdown](https://github.com/wkentaro/gdown/):

```
url = '...'
output = '/content/gdrive/Team Drives/AndSoOn.../Data.zip'
gdown.download(url, output, quiet=True)
```

After some time I get this message:

```
[Errno 28] No space left on device
```

Now I'm asking how to store such a large file through google colab. According to [Google](https://support.cloudhq.net/google-team-drive-technical-specifications-and-limitations/) it's possible to upload files up to 5 TB in size.

Comment: Hmm, the way that Colab works with Drive, I suspect the file will be buffered on the local disk, which isn't large enough to buffer a 80 GB file. Is there a way you can transfer it to Drive some other way?

Comment: @BobSmith I tried it today with downloading the file splitted using curl. I saved the parts in the team drive, but when I want to combine them to get the archive I get the same error: `cat: write error: No space left on device`